# Highcharts - Draw Crosshairs / Tooltip on Mouse Position Instead of Snapping to Data Point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Here (see this jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/crosshairs-both/) you can see the 2-dimensional crosshairs are snapping to the datapoint that is closest to it.  How would you make the crosshairs and tooltip correspond to the current mouse position on the chart?

```
tooltip: {
  crosshairs: [true, true]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[jsFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/t9waB/)

I ended up binding my own mousemove event to get the constantly changing mouse position within the graph for the crosshairs.  For the tooltip i just used:

```
tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            followPointer: true
        },
```

This should be more than enough to get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately crosshair works only in this way, but you can prepare your own solution by mouseOver and mouseOut events and add draw line by renderer.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.mouseOut

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: Are there any examples of this via jsfiddle?  I would give my right arm for one :)

Comment: Example of using renderer and events are avaiable as realted links in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

You can try it
[Set axis crosshair for mouse move](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis/Set_axis_crosshair_for_mouse_move.htm)

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highchartsDemo/s/set_axis_crosshair_for_mouse_move_example.htm)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [6, 4, 2,4],
        name: 'First'
    }, {
        data: [7, 3, 2],
        name: 'Second'
    }, {
        data: [9, 4, 8],
        name: 'asdf'
    }]        
});
```

Comment: This is the way, 4 years later in 2021. Superb!